# nginx configs to haproxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy, http-1.1

I want equivalent of nginx config in haproxy. Went through lot of links but none of them mentioned anything related to below configs.

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: Haproxy forwards request to backend server in http1.0 but my backend server support http1.1 and above.Earlier I was able to achieve this with nginx with abv configs but not with hap.  I have simple hap backend conf 


`backend tune
    server tune <ip>:443 check ssl verify none`
\n
\n
`* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the preferred [alpn](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#5.2-alpn) protocol on the server line and the header with [http-request set-header](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-header)

```
# I would prefer to set this option instead of the header
option http-server-close

http-request set-header Connection "''"
server 127.0.0.1:443 ssl crt pub.pem alpn http/1.1
```

You can also use [option http-server-close](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#4.2-option%20http-server-close)

Comment: I tried your suggestion for <br/><br/>
    
    `http-request set-header Connection ""
    server 127.0.0.1:443 ssl crt pub.pem alpn http/1.1`

in both cases it throws 'hap configuration file invalid' <br/><br/>

    `[ALERT] 153/143734 (27873) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:86]: 'http-request set- 
   header' expects exactly 2 arguments. <br/><br/>

    [ALERT] 153/144145 (28175) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:84] : 'server tune' 
    unknown keyword 'alpn'. Registered keywords :`

Comment: which version of haproxy do you use?

Comment: HA-Proxy version 1.8.15 2018/12/13

`http-request set-header Connection " ' ' "` \n\n
this worked. http1.1 not working still

Comment: you will need to update haproxy to 2.1 to be able to set `alpn`. Do the client send the HTTP/1.0 request? Maybe you will need to set the host header `http-request set-header Host <HOST_OF_BACKEND>`